# Which UIApplicationDelegate function should I implement for handling push notifications

Tags: ios, apple-push-notifications

I want to handle the tapping on a remote notification, and I see that there are two functions I can use:

```
application:didReceiveRemoteNotification:fetchCompletionHandler:
```

and

```
application:didReceiveRemoteNotification:
```

[application(_:didReceiveRemoteNotification:) - UIApplicationDelegate Protocol Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIApplicationDelegate_Protocol/#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UIApplicationDelegate/application:didReceiveRemoteNotification:) states that

> Implement the
>   `application:didReceiveRemoteNotification:fetchCompletionHandler:`
>   method instead of this one whenever possible. If your delegate
>   implements both methods, the app object calls the
>   `application:didReceiveRemoteNotification:fetchCompletionHandler:`
>   method.

But when I implement this function, I'm getting this warning:

> You've implemented -[ application:didReceiveRemoteNotification:fetchCompletionHandler:], but you still need to add "remote-notification" to the list of your supported UIBackgroundModes in your Info.plist.

I don't want to use the background mode, but this function is more convenient to use than the `application:didReceiveRemoteNotification:` function, since it is getting called even if the app is not launched yet.

So I'm asking:

1. Should I use `application:didReceiveRemoteNotification:fetchCompletionHandler:` even though I don't need background mode?
2. Why are the docs telling me to use it whenever possible?
3. Can I ignore the warning I get?

Thanks in advance,
Amitai